# Python - timeit doesn't stop

Tags: python

I use Python3, Ubuntu 14.04 to run the following snippet. The timing() function never terminate. I suppose it is due to the Timer() function. Why? How can I fix it?

```
import subprocess

def timing():
    args = ("./a.out")
    print('start')
    popen = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    popen.wait()    
    print('end')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print('main')
    t=timeit.Timer("timing()","from __main__ import timing")
    print(t.timeit())
```

In the terminal, it shows:

```
main
start
end
start
end
start
...
```

The skeleton of the code is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2662147/2431648).

Comment: Does `a.out` terminate?  If you run `timing()` without the `timeit` part does it behave as you expect?

Comment: `a.out` will terminate. The execute time of `a.out` is supposed to be micro seconds. I tested to call `a.out` without using Timer(). It worked properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `timeit()` is going to try to run the sample code `1000000` times.  With processes starting and stopping that's likely going to take a long time.  You can pass a number to `timeit()` to make it run fewer tests, like say

```
print(t.timeit(100))
```

to just run it 100 times.