# Lightweight way to measure the time my code takes in Python without including background tasks

Tags: python, performance, time, profiling

Most advice I can find on how to tell how long a chunk of my code is taking falls into one of a few camps:

1. Use timeit
2. Grab a timestamp before and after the code in question runs and take the difference of the two. The timestamp may come from time.time, time.clock, timeit.default_timer, or time.perf_counter (see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685221/accurately-measure-time-python-function-takes/)). I'm particularly enamored of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136422/2829764) which uses a decorator.
3. Use a profiler

My understanding is that #2 and #1 (which are the same under the hood) tell me how much wall clock time has elapsed, which can include other processes in addition to my code. For example, the [documentation for time.perf_counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) says, "It does include time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide."

So I'm left with a profiler. I'd prefer not to use a profiler for two reasons: first, it slows my code down, and second, thus far I haven't found a nice way to invoke it. I'd rather use something like [the `@timeit` decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136422/2829764) than pass a string suitable for use with `exec`.

Can I get a measurement that's free of background stuff without going so far as to use a profiler?

Comment: What about `python <your-file>.py -mtimeit -s` ?

Comment: @alfasin, doesn't `python -mtimeit` have the same problem as using timeit in other contexts (whatever else the computer is doing in the background also gets picked up)?