# Some invocations of a Lambda function take much longer despite a warm start (not a duplicate)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, huggingface-transformers

**Note:** the question has been previously mistakenly marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685221/accurately-measure-time-python-function-takes). Please note that my question is about AWS Lambda and the issue is not how to measure execution time (my code measures time very accurately with millisecond precision). If you do think that the question is a duplicate, please leave a comment first, as it is difficult to reinstate a questions once closed.

Here is my AWS Lambda function:

```py
import json
import time
import pickle

def ms_now():
    return int(time.time_ns() / 1000000)

class Timer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = ms_now()

    def stop(self):
        return ms_now() - self.start

timer = Timer()

from punctuators.models import PunctCapSegModelONNX
model_name = "pcs_en"
model_sentences = PunctCapSegModelONNX.from_pretrained(model_name)

with open('model_embeddings.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    model_embeddings = pickle.load(file)

cold_start = True
init_time = timer.stop()
print("Time to initialize:", init_time, flush=True)

def segment_text(texts):
    sentences = model_sentences.infer(texts)
    sentences = [
        [(s, len(model_embeddings.tokenizer.encode(s))) for s in el]
         for el in sentences]
    return sentences

def get_embeddings(texts):
    return model_embeddings.encode(texts)

def compute(body):
    command = body['command']
    
    if command == 'ping':
        return 'success'

    texts = body['texts']

    if command == 'embeddings':
        result = get_embeddings(texts)
        return [el.tolist() for el in result]
    
    if command == 'sentences':
        return segment_text(texts)
    
    assert(False)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    global cold_start
    global init_time
    
    stats = {'cold_start': cold_start, 'init_time': init_time}
    cold_start = False
    init_time = 0

    stats['started'] = ms_now()
    result = compute(event['body'])
    stats['finished'] = ms_now()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        'body': {'result': result, 'stats': stats}
    }
```

This Lambda function, along with the packages and the models (so that those don't need to be downloaded), is deployed as a docker image.

In addition to the timestamps of when the function started and finished (not including the cold start initialization), the response contains the information about whether it was a cold start and how long it took to initialize. I have another function, which invokes this function 15 times in parallel.

The anomaly happens with the first of these parallel invocations. Usually, it takes ~300ms (computed as the difference of the timestamps in the response). But sometimes it takes 900ms and longer (with the same input).

This does not happen due to a cold start, since I have `init_time==0` in the response (when a cold start occurs, `init_time>6000`). It happens both with `command == 'embeddings'` and with `command == 'sentences'`.

What could be the explanation for these spikes? With a warm start, what can cause a Lambda function to take much longer than usual?

P.S. The [question at re:Post](https://repost.aws/questions/QUI-eP97dOQ-m6USeb4NP30g/some-invocations-of-a-lambda-function-take-much-longer-despite-a-warm-start)

Comment: As explained in the duplicate (I was the who closed your previous, now deleted question), "other processes running on the same computer may interfere with the timing " when you use wall clock. This is especially important when your code runs on a machine/machines that run code for lots of users.

Comment: That's why the `timeit` module, also referred to in the duplicate, runs the code you want to time *a lot* of times to give you the mean running time. Single time mesurements vary *wildly*, even on a machine you run and control completely, so they are worthless, as you are timing all the machine did while running your code, not your code alone.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thank you for leaving a comment. This happens only with the first of the 15 parallel invocations. If what you wrote were true, it would happen with other invocations as well. Secondly, it would sometimes be 400ms, sometimes 500ms etc. But it is always way longer, in the range of 900ms. Also, AWS Lambda environment is created on request and is rarely under-provisioned, with the timing results very consistent. Something related to how AWS Lambda operates is clearly going on here.

Comment: Presume this Lambda function is not configured to connect to your VPC.

Comment: @jarmod It does not have any VPC configuration.